# How to counter 3. Nf3 f5 in the King's Gambit Declined

Tags: opening, kings-gambit

I've read about many of the basic variations of the KGD, e.g. [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Gambit#King.27s_Gambit_Declined) but none of of them mention the following from Black. This suggests to me that this move may be a mistake from black that I could take advantage of, but I see nowhere good for white to go from here.

What should white play next?

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. e4 e5 2.f4 d6 3. Nf3 f5
```

Comment: Just pointing out, if you want something similar to chew on, that the line you give shares a spirit with the Philidor Counter Gambit, `1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 f5`, which was the original idea behind the Philidor Defense: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philidor_Defence#Philidor.27s_original_intention:_3...f5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3...f5 is not a very good move, but it's not a terrible one; there's no immediate refutation. White's best response (verified with the chess program Houdini) is probably to deal with the pressure on his e-pawn by playing 4.exf5 Bxf5 (4.d3 would be passive; 4.Nc3 fxe4 5.Nxe4 d5 gives Black a nice center), then continue to develop, say with 5.Nc3 (covering e4 so that fxe5 is a real threat; if 5.fxe5 dxe5 6.Nxe5 now then 6...Qh4+ 7.g3 Qe4+ double-attacking the knight and rook). White's position is more pleasant but Black is certainly not lost.